# Javascript fullcalendar prod server vs dev machine issue

Tags: javascript, iis, fullcalendar

```
 <div id='calendar'></div>
```

Is the html tag that the fullcalendar uses to insert a calendar and do its magic.  It's a great tool, but something weird is happening.

My calendar is created with events from the DB and all that stuff works well.  Here's the issue...

Calendar on 2 pages - both work great on dev workstation.
Deployment - works on one page, but not on the other.  The calendar div gets populated with some complex tables etc for rendering.  Except this doesn't happen  - ONLY on one page, ONLY on the production server - same browser.  All the db stuff is there, pages coming back are identical other than the table stuff that gets inserted on my dev machine, but not when server from production.  But again, the same control works just fine from prod on another page - stumped!  Web server is IIS 7

Any thoughts or even wild speculations most welcome!!

Comment: Not sure which browser you're using, but open up a development section/network "Tab" and make sure all resources are being loaded. That is to say you're not, behind the scenes, getting a 404 on the calendar script file or other resources necessary to render the page.

Comment: You're a brilliant man Mr. Christie!! I had a relative path that was breaking but fixed now!  Thanks a ton...

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it an official answer...

Commonly when something doesn't render in either a development or production settings but does in the other environment you're experiencing an absent resource. This is usually something along the lines of requiring the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..path/to/script.js"></script>
```

Since one location *has* the file in that location and the other doesn't, you can run in to scenarios where it works in one spot but not the other.

Easiest method to confirm this is to open the debugger in your favorite browser and use the "networking" section to determine if all the resources are loading correctly (and are resolved). Otherwise, chances are the page that's not working is getting a 404 (or other error) when trying to retrieve the file it needs and thus the page fails to operate.